# Is there a way to resolve/update an older System.Runtime.Loader?

Tags: mysql, xamarin

I'm facing difficulties in getting my Xamarin app to connect to my server.

When I try to run this code:

```
try
        {
            // connect to the mySQL server
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            // create an open connection (this logs into the server)
            connection.Open();
```

I encounter an error at connection.Open(); and it throws the following exception:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager' threw an exception.-   
$exception  {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies,
```

It looks like I'm missing a file called System.Runtime.Loader with a version 4. And after checking the assets I found that I had this file but it's version is an older 1.0.24212.1. What steps could I take to try to fix this problem?

Comment: first, connecting directly from a mobile client to a db server is a horrible idea and you should avoid it at all costs.  Second, there are numerous articles, posts, tutorials, etc about using Xamarin and MySQL.  Have you read them?  Based on your post there is no indication of what libraries or nugets you are trying to use.

Comment: @jason I didn't know that it was a horrible idea. I have done all of those things. I'm using MySql.Data.

Comment: Are you using the Xamarin MySQL plugin?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635808/can-i-create-a-cross-platform-app-with-xamarin-using-a-mysql-database

Comment: That nugget broke my code. But I'm going to look into rest API. I don't want hackers to get into my program.

Comment: This app will not be available to the public.

Comment: even if your app isn't public, your DB server will be exposed to the world

Comment: regardless, if you have problems using the Xamarin MySQL plugin, you need to post the details of those errors if you need further help

Comment: @jason I wish I could discuss this stuff with you, you've always been helpful in here. I just don't have enough points yet to enter a discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the program running with the nugget package @Jason mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635808/can-i-create-a-cross-platform-app-with-xamarin-using-a-mysql-database). It is ill advised to connect to SQL in this manner as your program can be de-compiled and your server information stolen.